# how to create Oracle DBLink in same SID

Tags: oracle

Please let me know how to create Oracle DBLink in the same SID for two schema? To make clear, I want to connect one schema to another schema in the same Oracle server (SID).

Let's say, I have two schema called sch1 and sch2. Now, I login as sch1 and what I want is to retrieve data from sch2 (as long as I'm in sch1).

Comment: You don't need a DBLink for that. Just query the "other" schema.

Comment: any coding to show as example?

Comment: Database links are completely the wrong way to go here.  When you say 'connect one schema to another', what *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: @ppshein: Just run a select with a fully qualified table name: `select * from otherschema.thetable` The user needs to have the approriate privileges of course.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yap, I've already tried like your example. But, got error is "table or view doesn't exist". I think, I've already done making for approriate privileges.

Comment: @LukeWoodward let's say, I've two schema in same SID. sch1 and sch2. I want to retrieve data from sch2 when I login as sch1.

Comment: Connect as `sch2`, run `grant select on sometable to sch1`.  Then connect as `sch1` and try `select * from sch1.sometable`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Can you post this answer? Then I'll mark as correct answer.

Comment: @pshein: done.  Please note also that the last query in my previous comment should have been `select * from sch2.sometable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access a table in one schema from another schema, try doing the following:

- connect as `schema2`,
- run `grant select on sometable to schema1`,
- connect as `schema1`,
- try `select * from schema2.sometable`.